# Country/State Dropdown in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

How do i deal with dependent combo boxes in the views with the form helper. For example:

Country Select Box (Choosing a country shall filter out the states of the selected country)
States Select Box

This should happen with the help of Javascript / Jquery etc. I came across an example for the same with Cake's core AJAX helper but it would be very nice if someone can help with a Javascript example.

Thanks

Comment: Did the solution provided by @gong worked for you? Please confirm!

Answer (score 8):

In views/ edit.ctp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('#country').change(function() {
   $('#state').load('/controller/getStates/'+$(this).val());
 });
});
</script>
<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="1">Greece</option>
</select>

<span id="state">
<select name="state">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</span>
```

and in controller.php

```
function getStates(int countryID){
  $this->set('selectbox',
    $this->State->find('list',array('conditions'=>'State.Country_id='.$countryID,
      'fields;=>array('description')));
}
```

and views/getStates.ctp

```
<select name="state">
<option value=""></option>

<?php 
foreach($selectbox as $option) 
  echo '<option value="'.$option['id'].'">'.$option['description'].'</option>'."\n";
?>
</select>
```

I hope I don't forget something

Comment: To which version of CakePHP does this solution apply?

Answer (score 2):

@gong's solution works well. Just remember to add:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

in the controller and ensure there is a clean ajax.ctp in the layouts folder... otherwise all the layout code will be returned in the ajax response as well as just the dropdown code!

Answer (score -2):

```
    $states = $this->State->find('list', array(
            'conditions' => array('State.country_id' =>$codePassed),
            'order'=>array('State.stateName ASC'),
            'fields' =>array('id','stateName'),
            'recursive' => -1
            ));
    $a='';
    $a.= "<select name=\"state\">";
    $a.= "<option value=\"\">Select state</option>";
    foreach($states as $key=>$value){
        $a.="<option value=\"$key\">".$value."</option>";
    }
    $a.="</select>";
```

Comment: You're constructing HTML in the controller, ignoring the helper designed to do exactly that. This is not good practice. Additionally, this doesn't address the question at all.