# CakePHP AJAX City / State dropdown population

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP application that has a City / State dropdown box (to prevent user error on input).  We have a controller / database table called "Cities" that contains each city in the US along with State, Zip, Lat and Lng.  I've included the creation code for the table below for reference.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
    `zip` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lat` decimal(8,6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lng` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

For my Cities controller (controllers/CitiesController.php), I have two custom find functions to help populate the dropdown (via JSON)

```
class CitiesController extends AppController {

    public function getstates() {
        $this->set('states', $this->City->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('DISTINCT City.state'),
            'order' => 'City.state ASC',
            'group' => 'City.state',
            'recursive' => 0
        )));    
        $this->set('_serialize', array('states'));
    }

    public function getCitiesInState($state) {
        $this->set('cities', $this->City->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('City.city', 'City.zip', 'City.lat', 'City.lng'),
            'order' => 'City.city ASC',
            'group' => 'City.city',
            'conditions' => array('City.state = ' => strtoupper($state)),
            'recursive' => 0
        )));
        $this->set('_serialize', array('cities'));  
    }
}
```

Now this is where I am having a problem.

I am trying to implement this on another models "Add" method (views/Facilities/add.ctp).  I'm not sure the best way to call the data for the dropdown.  I know I will want to make a jQuery onchange event tied to the States dropdown, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872282/722617

The models are associated, the "Facilities" model has a foreign key of "city_id" that is tied to the id of the city from the Cities model.

The current code just lists all the cities in the database, and looks as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('city_id', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'City Id'));?>
</div>
```

Any suggestions for properly implementing this code?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're having a problem with.  However, I would design your application differently.  For one, not all cities have a single zip code.  For two, the state field in city should be instead a foreign key to a different table to hold the names of all the states.

Comment: This was an open-source database I used for the cities / states.  If there is a city with multiple zip codes it is listed for each zip code, so that isn't a problem with lookups.
I agree that it could be broken into a cities / states table, but I didn't think that seemed necessary since I can map state names programmatically if desired.

Comment: It's not great database design to have duplicated data like that.  What if a state or a city is entered in with misspellings in some of the entries, or some such.  Now you have to go in and edit each one.  Better to keep it centralized.  Also, you save on space if you store foreign keys rather than repeated use of the same set of strings.

Comment: That is true.  Typically I am all about breaking up content to make a database as normalized as possible.  I guess laziness kicked in when I found a DB table fully ready for me of the data I was looking for.

Well I can re-write the controller pieces to break those up, but will still have the same issue I am having now

Comment: Did you by any chance stumble upon [this article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) which has an example of such a chained dropdown in CakePHP and even live code examples to look at?

Comment: Mark, I  did not come across that article.  Looks very helpful, I'm going to give that one a try, Upvoted. Thanks!